# How to upload files to remote server using curl on Ubuntu 18?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-18.04, curl

I have noticed that my application on Ubuntu 18 is not uploading files to remote server which was working ok on Ubuntu 16.

When I do trace I see only one difference.

Ubuntu 16:
Content-Disposition: **form-data**

Ubuntu 18:
Content-Disposition: **attachment**

Curl command:

```
curl --trace-ascii - -XPOST -u user:password  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed' \
    -H 'If-Match: '"e4a49f13"'' -F 'file-delete={"delete":[]};type=application/json' \
    -F 'file-put-1=@test.txt;filename=destinationFile.txt;type=text/plain' \
    'http://192.168.1.20:8081/applications/14837348?content=RAW'
```

Versions:
Ubuntu 16: curl 7.47.0
Ubuntu 18: curl 7.58.0

I have tried also to install from source https://github.com/curl/curl.git

Found this reported issue: https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/5256

Thank you all for help

Comment: Why did you override the Content-Type? That is probably the problem.

Comment: @MichaelHampton but why is working on ubuntu 16?

Comment: Who knows? Maybe the old version ignored your attempt to override the header, and the new version doesn't. Maybe it was a bug that they fixed. Maybe I'm completely wrong and the problem lies elsewhere. But you can at least try it and find out whether it works.

Comment: @MichaelHampton it works if I remove Content-Type :)

Answer (score 0):

Can try the following command to upload file to a remote server provided the necessary authentication is assigned

curl -F ‘data=local file path’ Destination address

Same -F option can be provided to upload multiple files.

try this, if not working let me know